# How to get table header value using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having problem with getting table header value using jquery function.
I have timetable module.in that the view page contains table format like period_timing and weekdays.

```
 days   09.00AM - 10.00AM   10.00Am-11.00AM  11.00AM-12.00PM  ........

 Mon         Assign             Assign           Assign

 Tues        Assign             Assign           Assign

 Wed         Assign             Assign           Assign

 ..
```

In this Table Days are stored in weekday model and period timings are in Period_timing model.When I click assign link it shows the modal window(popup window). which contains subject_id label.We can select subjects from drop down list. while saving subject in popup window.it send subject_id in params. But I need weekday_id and Period_timing_id also. so, I have tried jquery for getting table header value .Is it correct way for getting period_timing id and weekday_ids.

And also I have included coding.

In Controller

```
def timetable
     @timetable_entry =   TimetableEntry.new(params[:subject_id])

    if params[:course].present?
      @timetable = CoursePeriod.where(:course_id => params[:course])

      @view = @timetable.first.period_timings

      @week = WeekdayEntry.where(:status=> true).pluck(:weekday_id)
      @first_day  = Weekday.find(@week[0]).day
      @second_day = Weekday.find(@week[1]).day
      @third_day  = Weekday.find(@week[2]).day
      @fourth_day = Weekday.find(@week[3]).day
      @fifth_day  = Weekday.find(@week[4]).day
      render :partial => "table"

  end
end



 def subject_entry  
  #raise params.inspect      
    TimetableEntry.create(:subject_id => params[:timetable_entry][:subject_id])
  end
```

In View _table.html.erb

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Days &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <% @view.each do |i| %> 
            <th><%=i.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") %>--<%= i.end_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") %></th>
               <% end %>         
    </thead>
         <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= @first_day %></td>
                   <% (1..@view.count).each do |j|%>

                   <td><%= link_to "Assign","#myModal", :class => "assign", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                     <h3 id="myModalLabel">Timetable Entries</h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <%= form_for (@timetable_entry),url: subject_entry_path, method: :get do |f| %>
                    <%= f.label :subject_id %>

                    <%= f.select :subject_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Subject.all,"id", "name"),class: "display_mark",:prompt => "--Select--" %>
                    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>

                </div>

               </td>
                  <% end %>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td><%= @second_day %></td>
                     <% (1..@view.count).each do |j|%>
                     <td><%= link_to "Assign", "#myModal", :class => "", "data-toggle" => "modal" %></td>
                  <% end %>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td><%= @third_day %></td>
                   <% (1..@view.count).each do |j|%>
                   <td><%= link_to "Assign", "#myModal", :class => "", "data-toggle" => "modal" %></td>
                  <% end %>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td><%= @fourth_day %></td>
                   <% (1..@view.count).each do |j|%>
                   <td><%= link_to "Assign", "#myModal", :class => "", "data-toggle" => "modal" %></td>
                  <% end %>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td><%= @fifth_day %></td>
                   <% (1..@view.count).each do |j|%>
                   <td><%= link_to "Assign", "#myModal", :class => "", "data-toggle" => "modal" %></td>
                  <% end %>
                </tr>
        </tbody>      

</table>
```

And I tried jquery for getting table header value. But which shows Days text.

```
$("body").on('click', '.assign', function(){
    var col = $(this).prevAll().length;
  var headerObj = $(this).parents('table').find('th').eq(col);
   // A quick test!
  alert("My cell header is called: " + headerObj.text());
});
```

Please Share your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get respective column header:

```
$("body").on('click', '.assign', function(){
  var headerObj = $(this).parents('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());
   // A quick test!
  alert("My cell header is called: " + headerObj.text());
});
```

Try below code to get days values like monday,tuesday,..etc.,:

```
$("body").on('click', '.assign', function(){
    var headerObj = $(this).siblings('td:first-child');
   // A quick test!
  alert(headerObj.text());
});
```

**NOTE:** You can use `$(document)` instead of `$("body")` it's way too high in the DOM.

Comment: How to get monday,tuesday ..from table

Answer (score 0):

Try var headerObj = $(this).parents('table').find('thead').find('th').eq(col);

Comment: FYI.Using this code I got days text. But, how to get period_timings dynamically.(i.e 09.00AM - 10.00AM)